# Make sure object has specific keys which are derived from a Enum and specific values for those keys

Tags: typescript

I have these modules(CAR, BUS) in my app and I would like to have everything else related to those linked to this enum. For an example I have a config file, there I want configs for any of above modules but they should always relate to the above modules. So config objects should use module name from enum as the key.

Following is a example I created out my actual scenario.

```
enum Vehicles {
  CAR = "car",
  BUS = "bus"
}

type VehicleKeys = keyof typeof Vehicles;

type VehicleValues = `${Vehicles}`;

interface CarConfig{
  engine: string;
};

interface BusConfig{
  color: string
}

/**
 * {
 *  car: CarConfig;
 *  bus: BusConfig;
 * }
 */

type VehicleConfig = { [K in VehicleValues]?: CarConfig | BusConfig }; 

interface Config extends VehicleConfig {
  name: string,
}

const config: Config = {
  name: "test",
  car: {
    engine: "My Car",
  },
  bus: {
    color: "Red",
  }
}

if(config.car){
  console.log( config.car.engine)
}
```

Since I want config keys to be limited to keys of enum I used **[K in VehicleValues]**. So no one is going to add plane into config unless PLANE is in the enum. But the problem is now I cannot specify which interface is relevant to which key.

```
/**
 * {
 *  car: CarConfig;
 *  bus: BusConfig;
 * }
 */
```

I can go with any of the interfaces but then there is a problem accessing value bcz compiler doesn't know which type the data is.

```
Property 'engine' does not exist on type 'CarConfig | BusConfig'.
  Property 'engine' does not exist on type 'BusConfig'.
```

Can I still restrict the keys and ensure which interface should it's value be?

Sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-pm1hh?file=/index.ts)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't declare it as you show in the commented out part? As it is, you say that a `car` property can be a Bus or Car and a `bus` can also be a Bus or a Car.

Comment: @crashmstr I don't keys other than what is in enum ( car and bus ) to be in config. If hard coded it is the awareness of developer to know the connection between the enum and the config. I'm trying to force it.

Comment: You force it by typing a `car` as a `CarConfig` and a `bus` as a `BusConfig` in your `Config` type. Otherwise, there is nothing to prevent them from being assigned the wrong type, and, in addition, you need to narrow the type to access the properties as you can see.

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbkY9W) what you're looking for?  If so, I'm happy to write up an answer; if not, please clarify.

Comment: @jcalz Oh yes. Darn I have overthink this. Thanks a lot. Can you post it separately so I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can define types with *computed property keys* as long as those keys are of a [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) or [`unique symbol`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#unique-symbol) type.  And [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) values like `Vehicles.CAR` and `Vehicles.BUS` count as literal types for this purpose.  So you could write `Config` as

```
interface Config {
    name: string;
    [Vehicles.CAR]?: CarConfig,
    [Vehicles.BUS]?: BusConfig
}
```

and everything should work as you desire:

```
const config: Config = {
    name: "test",
    car: {
        engine: "My Car"
    },
    bus: {
        color: "Red"
    }
};

if (config.car) {
    console.log(config.car.engine); // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=32&pln=19&pc=18#code/KYOwrgtgBAasAWBLAxgG2AZygbwFBQKgGEBBAJSgF4oAiZAQwCcaAafQgIQFUBlK2gEZgMNXAF9cuAC4BPAA7BYCFOgDSwGVmoBrDQHsAZlFkLDSpGkwBuSScVwL6GPVRhM-O2YcrMAbV0yZp5G3pYYALo2uIggUsCMBvTIikRMRHogBogA5jjsBKDZMcAAXFAYUowx2TYS0bHxiclQHMLpmTl5hFDIeqh6jGUVVSA14pIxcQlJKRlZuXjdIPQQpeWV1TbdvqHoGAB0pGThAPxlqYzt82zbu5j73DynZa0YVznjkr0gFT1zOed-rlqItCMtVmUaHEKqx8j0mGVQd0CqNipCALIyYhMUTdMQ3QhCDCIuHdXr9Qa0MjAAAmuMIEjEUUQRgAFN95vsGIwAJRdQjfDB9YD7frZdlArlMfaFYo8qxQAD0iqgem09BknyAA)

Comment: The OP doesn't want additional properties added to the `config` object. The gymnastics with the `VehicleConfig` is to create an `interface` that behaves like a `type`... i.e., an interface that cannot be re-opened.

Comment: I'm not sure that the OP is really talking about preventing interface merging; that's kind of a strange thing to want and your answer doesn't show it (see [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXRXJm)). Preventing additional properties in values is hard to do in TypeScript since object types are not closed, regardless of interface/type alias (see [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3Apkw)). Conversely, excess property checking, on which your answer seems to rely, also kicks in regadless (see [this](https://tsplay.dev/mA7kZw)).

Comment: This is the comment that the OP posted on my original (now deleted) answer: "_Someone can add something else here. eg interface Config { car?: CarConfig, bus?: BusConfig, plane?: PlaneConfig, } Yet plane is not in the Vehicles enum. I'm trying to force that connection._"

Comment: So if the objection was that someone can literally add properties to the interface at its declaration, that isn't even merging; it's just editing source code.  That's not preventable at all, right?  Someone can write `type Config = {car?: CarConfig, bus?: BusConfig, plane?: PlaneConfig }` just as easily.  I think *maybe* the OP wants to use the computed properties, so `[Vehicles.CAR]` instead of `car`, which would communicate that the intended values come from the enum, but we'll have to wait and see.  But no matter what, nothing can prevent someone from editing the original type definitions.

Comment: I would love if there is a ts error when a key not in the enum getting added to the config object. That is why I tried using `[K in VehicleValues]` but there I cannot specify which value can be assigned to which key. @jcalz 's answer is the closes I got to what I want, so it communicates the relationship to the enum to the develop.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using an `interface` which, by design, [allows authors to add additional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces). If you want to restrict the allowed properties, just use a `type` instead:

```ts
interface CarConfig {
    engine: string;
};

interface BusConfig {
    color: string
}

type Config = {
    name: string,
    car?: CarConfig,
    bus?: BusConfig,
}

const config: Config = {
    name: "test",
    car: {
        engine: "My Car",
    },
    bus: {
        color: "Red",
    },
    /*
        Type '{ name: string; car: { engine: string; }; bus: { color: string; }; plane: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Config'.
          Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'plane' does not exist in type 'Config'.ts(2322)
    */
    plane: {},
}
```

Comment: This way there is no relationship enforced ( via ts compiler ) nor inferred. My original intention is to enforce this via ts. If someone tries to add `plane?: PlaneConfig` to `Config` without adding it to `Vehicles` enum it ts can give a error that would be awesome.

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to do this. Preventing a fellow programmer from editing source code is not really the intention of the TypeScript compiler. Your current solution would already allow the addition of a `plane` property the same way the it allows the addition of that `name` property of type `string`.

Comment: @SusithaRavindaSenarath - Are you trying to prevent the `plane` property from being added to the Config **interface** or the config **object**? Because even jcalz's answer doesn't prevent a programmer from adding `place` to the **interface**.

Comment: This is a simplified sample of a large app with lots of functionality. So there is a chance of people doing crazy things. As I said it would be awesome if keys in `Config` can be restricted to values of enum. With `jcalz` suggestion at lease person to add something to `Config` realize there is a relationship to `Vehicles` enum. What I tried ( `[K in VehicleValues]` ) ensures nothing new can be added but I cannot specify the value type like that.